# User with very low rep editing questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, reputation

I just found [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13162665). [The user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6613600/tropiks) has only **15 rep** and is totally inactive on Stack Overflow. How is it possible that they can edit a question?

Comment: Editing at 15 rep isn't a thing. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12283834) was the very first thing I did after joining Stack Overflow and [being informed](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: Site reputation alone is not indicative of knowledge in such narrow professional subject. Demonstrated competence in the tag subject is IMO a more accurate editor's qualifier, including low rep users. It may always be beneficial to consult others (i.e. suggest edits), when it comes to someone else's rich enough content, like the one you linked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All users can **suggest** edits.

That is why we have a suggested edit review queue - to review the **suggested** edits and approve or reject them.

Only once a user has the edit posts privilege (2,000 rep on SO) can they edit directly without going through the review queue.

Comment: Ok thanks.I guess I just cant remember how things were when I was low rep :-) Sorry for the stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

You can even suggest edits as an anonymous user - you don't need any reputation at all. Just try to log out and see for yourself. The edits will be reviewed by people with enough reputation to know if they are correct or not.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately.